# Is it possible to determine the direction of a visual selection in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I want to visually select some lines and then paste a copy of the commented-out selection either above or below the original selection, depending upon whether the visual selection was created upwards or downwards. So if I start visual mode on line 100 and move the cursor up 10 lines, that would be an upward visual selection, whereas if I start at line 100 and move the cursor down 10 lines it would be a downward selection. `line("'<")` and `line("'>")` are identical in both cases so it looks like Vim always chooses the lesser number as the selection start. Is there a way to determine if the visual selection was upward or downward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When (in your mapping / command) you first exit visual mode via `<Esc>`, you can compare the position / line of the cursor (`line('.')`) with the `'<` and `'>` marks. Then just use the marks (they keep their values even when visual mode is left), or re-select via `:normal! gv`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a mark before you start selection and another one when you leave the selection:

```
ma
V
jjj
<Esc>
mb
```

and then see if `line("'a") < line("'b")`.